# Not getting the owner of the group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am using below command to get the owner of a group using PowerShell but it always return blank.

```
Get-ADGroup <groupName> | Select-Object -Property Managedby
```

It is giving blank output

```
Managedby
---------
```

Comment: FTR, manager and owner are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

I guess

```
Get-ADGroup -Filter * -Properties ManagedBy | Select-Object -Property Managedby
```

would work better.

`ManagedBy` is not included in the default properties listed when getting a group object.